# Detect color in the middle of image (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, color-picker, roi

I have these 3 images (consider "image" the whole square not only the figure inside - this is just for demonstration purposes):

[image: im1] [image: im2] [image: im3]

What I want to do is detect the colour in the middle (center) of each one. So, having an area (square or circle) in the center and with OpenCV detect which is the colour.
Something like a color picker...

The purpose is to have 3 values, 3 for each image (BGR).

Example:

[image: im4]

What is the colour in the ROI ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Using this code I can find the middle of an image and apply a mask.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("im2.png")

height, width, depth = img.shape
circle_img = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)

mask = cv2.circle(circle_img, (int(width / 2), int(height / 2)), 20, 1, thickness=-1)
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=circle_img)

cv2.imshow("masked", masked_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now it remains to find BGR of the masked area (visible one...)

Comment: mean the pixel value of each pixel in your roi

Comment: What ? Can you explain more ? I thought about masks, histograms and hsv but what do you mean by "pixel value of each pixel" ? Meantime, thanks.

Comment: Histograms does not give you any information about "position", so is useless in what you want to do. I'm going to add more.

Comment: @Link it's not alright to take an answer on your own question, modify it, and post it as your own.

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
height, width = img.shape[:2]
# Change these values to fit the size of your region of interest
roi_size = 10 # (10x10)
roi_values = img[(height-roi_size)/2:(height+roi_size)/2,(width-roi_size)/2:(width+roi_size)/2]
mean_blue = np.mean(roi_values[:,:,0])
mean_green = np.mean(roi_values[:,:,1])
mean_red = np.mean(roi_values[:,:,2])

print("R: {}  G: {}  B: {}").format(mean_red, mean_green, mean_blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image is a `PhotoImage`, calculate middle point and fetch the colours:

```
r,g,b = image.get(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(path_to_image)

width, height = im.size #get image size

#since you do not specify the size of the center area in the question, just replace the below variables with what you want
left = (width - your_width)/2
top = (height - your_height)/2
right = (width + your_width)/2
bottom = (height + your_height)/2

im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) #crop the center of the image

rgb = im.convert('RGB') # get three R G B values
r, g, b = rgb.getpixel((1, 1))

print(r,g,b)
```

With OpenCV replace the two first lines with:

```
im = cv2.imread(path_to_image)
height, width = im.shape[:2]
```

Comment: He tagged "opencv".

Comment: @Moia it's easy to transform it though, plus PIL might be a better option for this

Answer (score 0):

You have an image of size w x h. Let's assume a roi size of 11 pixel per side, so offset = 5

Access the pixel from (w/2 - width/2, h/2 - height/2) to (w/2 + width/2, h/2 + height/2).

Then calculate the mean of all extracted pixel (so you're more robust to color variation).

You can of course change the color space if you want it in other space color depending of the kind of picture are you going to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the RGB value of the pixel in the center of image using OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

height, width, depth = img.shape
circle_img = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)

mask = cv2.circle(circle_img, (int(width / 2), int(height / 2)), 1, 1, thickness=-1)
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=circle_img)

circle_locations = mask == 1
bgr = img[circle_locations]

rgb = bgr[..., ::-1]

print(rgb)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179799/bgr-values-of-masked-image-opencv-python/50179921#50179921)